# Capacitor discharge at lower voltages

Tags: high-voltage, electrolytic-capacitor

**Question 1:**

I have been looking around and could not quite get my head around if the same principle of high voltage and low current conversion applies to capacitors as with "power lines".

For example, say you need 10V at 100A, you can get it from say 10,000V 0.01A by stepping it down to the required voltage and current.

Now, from what I understand of capacitors, with them you can store high voltage and high current (*correct me if I'm wrong*).

Will you be able to get, say, 10V at 1A from a 400V 22,000μF capacitor? Should it be stepped down?

**Question 2:**

400V across 10,000μF = 800J

800J for 1s = 800W

400V at 800W = 2A at 400V for 1s if this is right?

So if I pull 100V at 2A I could use it for 4 seconds?

Please guys, no confusing formulas as I use online calculators. I'm still getting to know this stuff first.

Answer (score 6):

You say *no confusing formulas*, but the problem with your not-understanding the issue is explained by at least *some simple formulas*, which I'll try to explain below in a simple way.

First of all it seems you confuse *power* with *energy*. Power is the *rate of change* of energy, i.e joules/seconds. When you have a current I flowing between two points across which there is a voltage V you have a power \$P=V\cdot I\$, i.e. there is an energy transfer of \$V\cdot I\$ joules for each second that passes.

Since energy, hence power, is subjected to the energy conservation principle (a very basic principle of nature), an ideal transformer, i.e. a transformer with no power losses, will put out as much power as it takes from its primary winding, so the relation \$V_1\cdot I_1=V_2\cdot I_2\$, which explains why stepping up the voltage corresponds to a stepped-down current.

With capacitors the story is completely different. First of all, capacitors don't accumulate power, but energy, according to the formula:

$$
U = \dfrac 1 2 \cdot C \cdot V^2
$$

where C is the capacitance and V the voltage across the cap. This is due to the separation of charge inside them. The relation between the voltage and the separated charge \$Q\$ is given by another simple formula:

$$
Q=C\cdot V
$$

Notice the problem: none of the formulas above gives a direct relationship between V and I for a capacitor, so it is not straightforward to know how much current you can get out of a capacitor charged at V volts!

Such a V-I relationship of course do exist, but it *is* a complicated formula (for someone with no clue about calculus):

$$
I = C \dfrac{dV}{dt} \qquad  \underbrace{\approx C \dfrac {\Delta V}{\Delta t}}
_{\text{this is an approximation} }
$$

To put it simple, that formula says that the current flowing through a cap is proportional (with C as proportionality constant) to the *rate of change of the voltage*.

Therefore you cannot know what current comes out of a cap unless you take discharge time into consideration. Technically speaking, the power is still given by \$V \cdot I\$, but I is not simply related to V for a cap, so knowing the way you draw current from a cap is fundamental to know how much power is delivered to the load.

Moreover, as @AndyAka as already pointed out, a simple resistor as a load is not the best you can do, because as the load draws current from the cap, the cap loses energy and its voltage will drop. Therefore it turns out that *a cap is not a good voltage source*.

**That means that there is no way to extract energy from the cap without lowering the voltage across it during the process.** That's what the energy formula above means for your question, and this can be shown better by inverting it:

$$
V = \sqrt{ \dfrac{2U}{C} }
$$

To use a cap as power supply, i.e. as a reasonably constant-voltage source, you have to use an enormously big cap (very high capacitance) and draw very little current from it during the entire discharge time, so that its charge varies little, and therefore its voltage varies little. This is explained by inverting the approximate I-V relationship above and looking at the result:

$$
\Delta V \approx \dfrac {I \cdot \Delta t} {C}
$$

The littler \$I\$ and \$\Delta t\$ and the bigger \$C\$ are, the lower is the voltage change \$\Delta V\$ across the cap. Note that this approximation is good as long as \$\Delta V\$ is much less than the current value of \$V\$ (say, \$ \Delta V < 0.1\cdot V\$).

Alternatively you can interpose a regulator circuit between the energy-storing cap and the load in order to keep the output voltage constant as long as possible. This is done, with various techniques, in some circuits exploiting a [supercapacitor's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) huge capacitance to power micropower circuitry (e.g. a CMOS real time clock chip in a PC).

Keep in mind, however, that the two situations you depicted are rather different in principle: in the transformer case you have a source of power (mains) connected to the primary which provides power in a continuous way to the transformer, so unlimited energy, as long as the power line is up and running. In the cap case *energy is limited* to what is stored in the cap, so the load cannot be powered forever, even if using a regulator circuit between the two.

Answer (score 3):

> Now from what i understand from capacitors is you can store high
>   voltage and high current(correct me if im wrong)

A capacitor stores charge and charge (Q) = capacitance x voltage so, you could say it stores voltage but you certainly can't say it stores current. The alternative to a capacitor is an inductor and this can "store" current but cannot (or does not) store voltage.

The current you can pull from a cap is pretty much unlimited. If you shorted out a capacitor, theoretically you would get infinite current but for practical purposes certainly tens if not hundreds of amps.

Unlike transformers, I'm not aware of capacitive transformer so it's bad news on that front if you were possibly considering that. As for the current you can get under load conditions your thinking is a little off-colour because as soon as you start withdrawing current, the voltage starts to drop - it won't remain constant - there is an exponential decay: -

[image]

The graph is telling you that if the capacitor was initially charged to 9V, as soon as you connect a resistor across it the voltage starts decaying to zero and roundabout at 5*C*R there is less than 1% of the starting voltage: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i forgot that voltage drops when you have a load. The actual reason i'm really asking this is because i cant understand how the whole "coil gun" concept works, i have seen with motor coils they usually demands high current. So the conversion between how much energy n capacitor stores and how much is fed to the coil of a coil gun is what i'm trying to figure out since capacitors cant store current, its supposed to have high voltage fed to create a strong magnetic field?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with coil guns.

Comment: @StevenFisher I belive this is how coil guns work: First you charge capacitors up with high voltage, storing the energy in electric field between the plates. And then you quickly discharge them thru the coils. The electric field gets "transformed" into magnetic field and the projectile flies away. The capacitors as "power supply" to the coils are a key since they have a moderately low resistance and can provide large amounts of current for a short period of time, which is what is needed for shooting the projectile.

Comment: @Golaž i understand that part but what i'm trying to get to know is how do you know what type and size of cap is needed for that certain coil and how much of a magnetic field it will be generating. Example where a 10 turn big gauge coil use 30V and 50Amps use to pull a big projectile with a small amount of force. How much uF will be needed to make it work? If you understand what i'm trying to say?

Comment: @StevenFisher I believe you have the answers to your original questions Steven and your supplementary question about choosing a coil gun capacitor is best put into a new question. If you can supply a typical circuit scheme for how the capacitor connects to the coil even I might be able to have an answer - just not that many people know about coil guns and a circuit is sure going to help.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can't store voltage or current inside a capacitor. You can only store charge which in turn creates electric field between the two plates of the capacitor. The energy of the capacitor is then stored in this electric field. The equations which describes the amount of energy a capacitor can store at a given voltage is as follows: $$W=\frac{C\times U^2}{2}$$

Also, you seem to confuse yourself with capacitor voltage rating, which in this case is 400V (the maximum voltage that can be safely applied to the capacitor) and the voltage that is actually across the charged capacitor. For the calaculations of energy stored, the voltage across the capacitor is what you need to look for. Taking this into account, we get: $$W=\frac{10\times 10^{-3}\times 10^2}{2}=0.5J$$

Now, when the capacitor is charging/discharging the voltage across it changes. $$I=C\times\frac{dU}{dt}$$
Which in turn changes the energy stored in the capacitor, so you cant just say that this is 0.5J for 1 second or 0.5W.

You can play around with [this online calculator](http://mustcalculate.com/electronics/capacitorchargeanddischarge.php) to see the current draw and voltage drop across the capacitor when charging/discharging.